# List Comprehensions to create pairwise dissimilarity

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm not familiar with list comprehensions but I would like to compute the bray-curtis dissimilarity using list comprehensions. The dissimilarity is given by

```
def bray(x):
    bray_diss = np.zeros((x.shape[0], x.shape[0]))
    for i in range(0, bray_diss.shape[0]):
        bray_diss[i,i] = 0
        for j in range(i+1, bray_diss.shape[0]):
            l1_diff = abs(x[i,:] - x[j,:])
            l1_sum = x[i,:] + x[j,:] + 1
            bray_diss[i,j] = l1_diff.sum() / l1_sum.sum()
            bray_diss[j,i] = bray_diss[i,j]
    return bray_diss
```

I tryed something like :

```
def bray(x):
    [[((abs(x[i,:] - x[j,:])).sum() / (x[i,:] + x[j,:] + 1).sum()) for j in range(0, x.shape[0])] for i in range(0, x.shape[0])]
```

without succes, and I can't figure out what is wrong! Moreover, in the first implementation, the second loop is not performed on all the matrix row values to save computation time, how is it possible to do it with list comprehension ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It will not make your code more readable.

Comment: You do not return anything with the comprehension (no `return / yield` statement). But, as  @LarsVegas said, it does not make your code more readable.

Comment: In order to use autograd, which do not support array assignment.

Comment: OK! thanks a lot for the return, I was not looking on the right direction! Any idea on the way to fill the top and bottom sides of the matrix simultaneously ?

Answer (score 0):

You won't gain anything wxith a list comprehension... except a better comprehension of list comprehensions!
What you have to understand is that list comprehension is a functional concept. I will not go in functional programming detail, 
but you have to keep in mind that functional programming forbids side effects. An example:

```
my_matrix = np.zeros(n, n)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        my_matrix[i,j] = value_of_cell(i,j)
```

The last line is a side effect: you modifiy the state of `my_matrix`. In contrast, a side effect free version would do:

```
np.array([[value_of_cell(i,j) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)])
```

You don't have the "create-then-assign" sequence: you create the matrix by declaring the values at each position. More precisely, to create a matrix:

- you have to declare a value for every cell;
- when you are given the pair `(i,j)`, you can't use it to declare the value of another cell (e.g. `(j,i)`)

(If you need to transform the matrix later, you have to recreate it. That's why this method may be expensive -- in time and space.)

Now, take look at your code. When you write a list comprehension, a good rule of thumb is to use auxiliary functions as they help to clean the code (we don't try to create a one-liner here):

```
def bray(x):
    n = x.shape[0] # cleaner than to repeat x.shape[0] everywhere
    def diss(i,j): # I hope it's correct
        l1_diff = abs(x[i,:] - x[j,:])
        l1_sum = x[i,:] + x[j,:] + 1
        return l1_diff.sum() / l1_sum.sum()

    bray_diss = np.zeros((n, n))
    for i in range(n): # range(n) = range(0,n)
        # bray_diss[i,i] = 0 <-- you don't need to set it to zero here
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            bray_diss[i,j] = diss(i,j)
            bray_diss[j,i] = bray_diss[i,j]
    return bray_diss
```

That's cleaner. What is the next step? In the code above, you choose to iterate over `j` that are greater than `i` and to set two values at once. But in a list comprehension, you don't choose the cells: the list comprehension gives you, for each cell, the coordinates and you have to declare the values.

First, let's try to set only one value per iteration, that is to use two loops:

```
def bray(x):
    ...

    bray_diss = np.zeros((n, n))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            bray_diss[i,j] = inner(i,j)

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i):
            bray_diss[i,j] = bray_diss[j,i]

    return bray_diss
```

That's better. Second, we need to assign a value to *every* cell of the matrix, not just prefill with zeroes and choose the cells we wan't to update:

```
def bray(x):
    ...

    bray_diss = np.zeros((n, n))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if j>i: # j in range(i+1, n)
                bray_diss[i,j] = inner(i,j) # top right corner
            else # j in range(i+1)
                bray_diss[i,j] = 0. # zeroes in the bottom left corner + diagonal

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if j<i: # j in range(i)
                bray_diss[i,j] = bray_diss[j,i] # fill the bottom left corner now
            else # j in range(i, n)
                bray_diss[i,j] = bray_diss[i,j] # top right corner + diagonal is already ok

    return bray_diss
```

A short version would be, using the "fake ternary conditional operator" of Python:

```
def bray(x):
    ...

    bray_diss = np.zeros((n, n))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            bray_diss[i,j] = inner(i,j) if j>i else 0.

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            bray_diss[i,j] = bray_diss[j,i] if j<i else bray_diss[i,j] 

    return bray_diss
```

Now we can turn this into list comprehensions:

```
def bray(x):
    ...

    bray_diss_top_right = np.array([[diss(i,j) if j>i else 0. for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)])
    bray_diss = np.array([[bray_diss_top_right[j,i] if j<i else bray_diss_top_right[i,j] for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)])
    return bray_diss
```

And, if I'm not wrong, it is even more simple like this (final version):

```
def bray(x):
    n = x.shape[0]
    def diss(i,j):
        l1_diff = abs(x[i,:] - x[j,:])
        l1_sum = x[i,:] + x[j,:] + 1
        return l1_diff.sum() / l1_sum.sum()

    bray_diss_top_right = np.array([[diss(i,j) if j>i else 0. for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)])
    return bray_diss_top_right + bray_diss_top_right.transpose()
```

Note that this version is *probably* (I didn't measure) slower than yours, but the way the matrix is built is, in my opinion, easier to grasp.